# How to use mlflow plugins in remote host ui

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, mlflow

I have an mlflow ec2 instance running on aws. I want to develop an mlflow plugin to save registered models to a specific aws s3 bucket.
I have read all the documentation on plugins for mlflow and, if my understanding is correct, to develop and use a plugin i need two things:

- Write the code for a pacakage following the mlflow plugins standards as in : https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/plugins.html
- Change the tracking uri by adding file-plugin: at the beginning:

  ```
  MLFLOW_TRACKING_URI=file-plugin:$(PWD)/mlruns python examples/quickstart/mlflow_tracking.py
  ```

Now, this is simple if I want the plugin to work on a python script. I just need to install my custom plugin package in my python environment and set the tracking uri as stated above.

However, if I want the same plugin to work when using the ui when connecting to my aws instance, I am not sure how to do it. I found no way to set the MLFLOW_TRACKING_URI to include file-plugin:.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue? How can I make sure my plugin works when interacting with mlflow through the ui?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I m afraid you are out of luck.. According to MLflow documentations, MLflow plugins are for the MLflow Python client https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/plugins.html thus you cannot influence the behaviour of the MLflow UI via the plugin since the UI interfaces directly with the MLflow REST API. There is a PR open since a long time about this topic, but nothing concrete has happened until today.. https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/issues/2440